# How do you fix the "Access Denied" error on a specific Dynamics CRM form?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

We have a Dynamics CRM 2015 (on-prem) form on a custom entity.

The form shows the following error when a user views an existing record unless:

> Access Is Denied
>
> You do not have enough privileges to access the Microsoft Dynamics CRM object or perform the requested operation. For more information, contact your Microsoft Dynamics CRM administrator.

The user has full Organisation level rights to the custom entity.

If we give the user sysadmin rights, the user can open the record using this form.

Creating a new form works fine (i.e. the user is able to open the record with the new form).

Stripping the original form of all fields (including lookups), libraries etc.. still shows the Access Denied error.

Anyone seen this before? Is this form corrupt? Is there any way to fix this form so that it no longer shows Access Denied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should [turn on trace](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699694.aspx), restart IIS and reproduce and error. After that investigate trace - it should contain explanation of an error. If it is not clear what's wrong - put trace message here.

Comment: It was the User UI Settings privilege that was missing! Thanks Andrii that helped.